# reset input type text using javascript?

Tags: jquery, html

i have small function that running on condintion, if text box value is not equal to "jitender"then alert will come up, but i also want reset the text box value if text box value is not equal to "jitender".

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var name= $('#name').val();
        if(name!='jitender'){
            alert("not valid name")

            }

        });

    });


<input type="text"  id="name"/>

<button>click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply add

```
  if(name!='jitender'){
            alert("not valid name");
            $('#name').val(''); //here comes clearing input
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var name= $('#name').val();
        if(name!='jitender'){
            alert("not valid name")
                $('#name').val(""); // this will reset the value
            }

        });

    });


<input type="text"  id="name"/>

<button>click me</button>
```

Comment: That will blank out the box.  Seems to me "reset" means "set back to what it was when the form was loaded".  May be the same thing in this case...may not.

Comment: The code do not modify the text-box. so "reset" means "make it empty" I guessed :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$('button').click(function(){
        var name = $("#name");
        if(name.val() != 'jitender'){
            alert("not valid name");
            name.val('');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        if($('#name').val() !='jitender'){
                alert("not valid name")
                $('#name').val(""); // resets value
            }

        });

    });​

<input type="text"  id="name"/>
<button>click me</button>​
```

heres the link so you can test: [Test the script](http://jsfiddle.net/pDs4C/160/)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call this after your alert - $('#name').val('newValue');

See here - http://api.jquery.com/val/